# Как раскидать картинки по папкам mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, ldpi?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, dpi

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, принцип того, как раскидать картинки по папкам `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `ldpi`. Вот у меня есть картинка размером 800x1280, как мне узнать, какой у нее `dpi`, чтобы  от него уже делать выводы, куда кидать... Я знаю, что `ldpi = 0.75`, `mdpi = 1.0`, `hdpi = 1.5`, `xhdpi = 2.0`.

Я просто хочу делать программы под разные экраны, но как делать, не знаю.

Comment: Так Вам надо понять, какой физический размер у картинки `800/dpi = дюймы` и в зависимости от этого положить в нужную папочку.

Comment: Что такое DPI? - это коэффициент метрики, который говорит сколько пикселов(точек) в дюйме. Андроид берёт нужную картинку в зависимости от дпи устройства. Вот побольше букв, далее говорите что конкретно Вам не понятно

Comment: https://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html

Comment: Я перечитал по тыщу разу developer androida, ну никак до сих пор не пойму, с dpi, mdpi, ldpi, hdpi я понял... Если экран маленький, то файл берется из ldpi, если чуть больше, то mdpi и т.д. Верно?

Comment: Тут дело не в маленький, большой. Экран может быть маленький, но с большой плотностью пикселей, и у него будет и xxdpi. Но примерно Вы поняли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dpi - зависит от разрешения экрана в пикселах и его физического размера в дюймах. Как узнать? Есть экран девайса 800 на 1280, (800Х800)+(1280Х1280) извлекаем корень = 1509,4.

Теперь магия. Если экран 4,7", то 1509,4/4,7 = 321 DPI ~ xhdpi (2.0), если хотим вашу картинку на весь экран на этом девайсе, то кладём её в xhdpi - это будет как бы базовый девайс. Для дугих девайсов кладём в mdpi картинку (400 на 640), в hdpi картинку (600 на 960) и так далее.

**Обновление**

Это на 100% работает в идеальном мире. ) Уж очень разные экраны бывают.  "Но ведь не может быть в mdpi базовым 800 на 1280" на экране в 9,4", будет.

Можете пересчитать. ) Можно прикинуть примерно и посмотреть на эмуляторе или в редакторе xml, как это будет выглядеть на разных девайсах. Вы можете закинуть эту картинку, не изменяя во все папки и тоже посмотреть, что будет. Android растянет или сожмёт. НО память будет не оптимально расходоваться. Не кидайте все картинки только в mdpi, на девайсах с высоким DPI некоторые (особенно большие) после принудительного увеличения могут очень много памяти съедать.

Comment: 1) У меня 480 на 800 4 дюйма. Значит будет 233, значит у меня 240 dpi HDPI, с этим я понял, все отлично.   
2) Есть беграунд картинка 800 на 1280. И как же узнать, какой DPI для него базовый, чтобы кинуть в папку, а оттуда уже расчеты делать? Если я кину в mdpi, то там все просто... 1,5 2,0 3,0. Но ведь не может быть в dmpi базовым 800 на 1280. Как я в телефон свой добавлю такую картинку базовую без изменений... он же не влезет.

Comment: А как быть то тогда емае)))...вот вы говорите что могут быть все экраны от 1 дюйма до 10 дюймов с ldpi mdpi hdpi xhdpi и т.д. А как сделать то тогда.

Я короче понял что mdpi dpi это что то типо качества. Хочешь чтобы картинка нормально отображалась на всех экранах надо это использовать....А как мне сделать чтобы в Андроид Ну хоть приблизительно посмотреть в Laout ах как будет отображаться картинка с 3 дйюмами 5 дюймами 7 8 9 и 10.....

Comment: Так я ж писал, в редакторе XML, если на графический вид перейти, можно выбрать экран, можно 10 сразу поставить и смотреть на каждом, или же эмуляторов создать разных. )

Comment: Дак там они разные от 2 и до 10 дюймов...2-4 ldpi 4-7mdpi 7-10hdpi 10+ xhdpi. И если допустим открыть в 5 дюймовом то треугольник справа...а если открыть 6 дюймов...то получаест открывается тот же layout и если я там изменю размер то в 5 Дюймовом треугольник будет еще меньше чем был, потому что размер в 6 дюймовом я уменшил....Дак вот я и хочу узнать где и как создавать эти лайотуы чтобы под каждый дюйм можно было редактировать по особому

Comment: Создайте ImageView, присвойте android:scaleType="fitCenter" в xml, картинку добавляйте через android:src="", за края не будет выходить.

Answer (score 0):

Оригинальную картинку надо масштабировать и ложить так:

- ldpi=36*36
- mdpi=48*48
- hdpi=72*27
- xhdpi=96*96
- xxhdpi=144*144
- xxxhdpi=192*192

А аппарат сам выберет какую из них показывать, не думай обо всяких `dpi`, ось сама о них позаботится

**Update**
Про картинки. Берете картинку в лучшем разрешении и объявляете ее `xxxhdpi`, далее по нисходящей масштабируете на `*dpi` сохраняя коэффициент сжатия аналогичный иконкам приведенным выше.

Comment: Да с иконками проблем нет. С картинками-то как быть?

Comment: @xTIGRx см. апдейт

Answer (score 0):

[@xTIGRx](/users/22339/xtigrx), могу Вам посоветовать воспользоваться [сайтом](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=33b5e5%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&backColor=ffffff%2C100). На нем Вы сможете переделать любую картинку под все необходимые Вам форматы за раз. Единственное неудобство этого сайта - готовые картинки называются ic_launcher. То есть приходит переименовывать каждую перед перемещением в проект.